# Oracle SQL 11g: How do I update the column so first letter of each word is capitalized?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

How do I update the column so first letter of each word is capitalized?

I tried using:

```
Update COUNTRIES  SET COUNTRYNAME=Upper(SUBSTR(COUNTRYNAME, 1, 1))
+SUBSTR(COUNTRYNAME, 2,LENGTH(COUNTRYNAME))
```

Comment: https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/data-quality/edqhelp/Content/processor_library/transformation/proper_case.htm

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions065.htm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use  `INITCAP()`

```
 Update COUNTRIES  SET COUNTRYNAME=INITCAP(COUNTRYNAME)
```

[oracle docs](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions065.htm)